# Swift4: Alamofire upload to s3 with presigned link and check md5

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, alamofire, md5, pre-signed-url

I am trying to implement upload to s3 via presigned link and validate md5 of file upload according to next s3 documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/)

I used next code, but nothing `Etag` header was returned

```
Alamofire.upload(data, to: presignedLink, method: .put, headers: ["Content-Type": " ", "x-amz-meta-md5chksum": md5]).responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response.response?.allHeaderFields)
            completion("bei raw data was updated")
        }
```

I found [next issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/675) that was mentioned other header name, `Content-MD5` and also claim that  `ContentMD5` should be added while presigned link get.

No luck with Alamofire, no `Etag` header was returned, but files are in my bucket and they looks fine.

I used [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) lib in order to calculate md5 string

Anyone tried such implementation?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: Nope :( No body use such solution